# 22.04.2 installed & working - I have 968 GBs of free space. Can I now also install Windows 10 and dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I tried for many, many days to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 on my Windows 10 computer so I could dual boot.  But I had many issues so and gave up. So I formatted my solid state drive into one partition, and I installed 22.04.2 with out issue.  As far as I can tell, everything is working just fine.

I have a great deal of free space.  At this point, can I install Windows 10?  If so, can someone direct me to a help file, or link on how to do this?

If it can not be done at this late date, then let me know and I will forget about it.

I would like to dual boot into Windows 10 or Ubuntu if possible.

Many thanks,
mraroid

Comment: No you cannot install another bare metal operating system to the free space on another system's partition. You would need to repartition. Also, it's best practice to install Windows *before* Ubuntu because Windows will overwrite GRUB.  I suggest that you start over. Install Windows first but make sure you leave enough **unpartitioned free space** for Ubuntu. Windows installation is off-topic here, but you can refer to the [official tutorial to install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you need additional help, refer to the tutorial when asking.

Comment: If you want dual-boot (not sure why), it's recommended to install dumber system first, Ubuntu installer can detect existing Windows insatllation, and will install in dual-boot next to it just fine, but as Windows is dumb, it would simply overwrite GRUB from Ubuntu if you install Windows after Ubuntu.

But what I actually recommend is not to use dual-boot, and instead use hypervisor (like QEMU/KVM) to run Windows. It will give you ability to use both system at same time.

Comment: Thank you Nmath & MIocik97 for your help.  I did a fresh install of Windows 10, then divided my 1 TB Samsung SS drive into two partitions.  I tried to install 22.04.2 from a flash drive after reading the install guides.  But after about two and a half 10/12 hour days, I failed over and over again, so I gave up.  I will look around for more info.  Many thanks.  mraroid

Comment: Can you give more diagnostic information about how/why the installation failed? Does it always fail at the same point of the installation? Do you have any errors or warning messages? What step(s) in the tutorial are you stuck on?

Comment: Nmath.  Every time I tried to install 22.04.2 it never saw my Windows 10 install.  I tried several times to have two partitions - one formatted for Windows, and another partition which I did not.  After the Windows install, I shut down the computer, plugged in the flash drive and booted.  When I ran Ubuntu from the flash drive all worked fine.  But when I tried to install, it never did see my Windows install.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't booting the Ubuntu USB in UEFI mode? The hard disk should have a GPT partition scheme. Windows will install as a UEFI operating system. You also need to install Ubuntu as UEFI, so you can't boot the USB in compatibility/legacy mode or it won't recognize Windows.